# How important are finite state machines in terms of application programming?

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern, state-machine

I'm senior computer science major, in my freshman year I took computer architecture course, and finite state machines were explained briefly. After freshman year, I never be taught finite state machine more detailed.
So I think finite state machines are also important  for application programming perspective.

I mean, when I think of strategy design pattern, we can easily do it by using finite state machine methodology.
What do you guys think?

Comment: For parsing things finite state machines can be very useful, but I don't see any similarities to the strategy pattern.

Comment: I mean based on the definition, strategy pattern encapsulates family of algorithms, and gives ability to dynamically set behavior given context, so in this sentence, does not 'context' mean status in model class?

Comment: The problem I have with this is that the strategy pattern is dynamic and finite state machines are not dynamic at all, but again this probably depends on the way how you look at it.

Comment: @NMertAydin your effort to integrate FSM to practice is interesting. Generally FSM is the architecture of any means of computing. Basically FSM is there in any place we write code. I still don't understand what you specially see in the context of Strategy pattern. You may add your ideas to your question, so that it would be more clear. :))

Comment: Many business processes can be modelled by FSMs and as such implementing them or using a suitable implementation is a good knowledge to have. Perhaps provide a bit more ideas in your question and we could further take this with more examples.